# The total derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the meaning of the total derivative.
So, please help me in understanding its geometrical aspects.
Like how do I see geometrically whether the total derivative exist or not at point?
I got confused when I saw that existence of directional derivative in all directions may not imply differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is not really universal. I guess that your total derivative is simply the derivative or differential. You will not see a derivative unless you can see the graph of your function, and this is reasonable only for a function of two variables. But even in this case it might be really hard to draw a 3D graph.

The derivative represents in a canonical way the tangent (hyper-)plane to the graph of a function. As such, it represents the best linear (i.e. Affine) approximation at a given point. It is a local-global object: it is local in the sense that it provides a linear approximation only around a point, but it is global in the sense that it provides an approximation in a whole neighborhood of that point. As you learned, directional derivatives represent the variation of the function only along a particular direction, and they don't even ensure continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The multi-dimensional case is not that much different from the one-dimensional case, where there are only two directions, left and right, instead of a range of directions. In 1D one insists as well that the directional limits from the left and from the right agree.

The general meaning of the total derivative is being the best linear approximation at the point of interest, be it as slope value or the linear map, depending on the definition.